# Laravel assertions full list

Tags: testing, laravel, laravel-4

PHP Laravel framework provides assertion methods like `->assertTrue()`, `->assertFalse()` for unit testing. However, I cannot find a full list of them. Are they documented somewhere? If not, where can I find them in Laravel source?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Your test cases all should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`. This class uses the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\AssertTrait`. Those are all the Laravel specific assertions.

[View on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/AssertionsTrait.php)

However `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` are both part of PHPUnit itself. You can find a list of all PHPUnit assertions on [the official website](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses PHPUnit and here is the list of phpunit assertions list:

https://gist.github.com/briankip/35e3506be8b1ecbcf3bb